# Delegates and inheritance in c#

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance, delegates

I have a bit of a problem with inheritance of delegates. Delegate as far as i understand is a pointer to a pair: an instance and a method, the thing is this is the method referenced in the creation of the delegate, and not affected by inheritance. So, this won't work:

```
public class BaseObject {
  public delegate void del();

  public BaseObject() {
    next=Method;
  }

  public del next;
  public void ExecuteNext() {
    next();
  }

  public virtual void Method() {
    Debug.Log("BASE");
  }
}

public class InheritedObject:BaseObject {
  override public void Method() {
    Debug.Log("INHERITED");
  }
}
...

(new InheritedObject()).ExecuteNext();
```

Execute runs the base Method(), I want it to run the inherited Method(). I have found some way around, but it is inefficient, distracting and very error prone, anyway here's the current working version that I'd like to get rid of:

```
class BaseObject {
  public delegate void del();

  BaseObject() {
    next=DoMethod;     /// using DoMethod here
  }

  public del next;
  public void ExecuteNext() {
    next();
  }


  public void DoMethod() {    /// using DoMethod here
    Method();
  }
  public virtual void Method() {
    // do base
  }
}

class InheritedObject:BaseObject {
  override public void Method() {
    // do inherited
  }
}

...

(new InheritedObject()).Execute();
```

This DoMethod aproach works but has many problems,

1. lots of useless code
2. error prone when using the class - easy to mistake obj.next=`DoMethod` with obj.next=`Method`
3. error prone when inheriting the class - I have to remember to not to inherit the DoMethod, and lots of virtual and overrides.

Any suggestions how can I do that better? Perhaps some annotation magic that does the `DoMethod` by itself? I've already thought of dictionaries - they aren't good here, they add even another level of confusion (Mono, .NET 2, Unity3d framework)

Comment: You could start with the reasoning behind this approach. Why do you need the delegate at all?

Comment: `(new InheritedObject()).Method();` works. As Daniel said, why the `delegate`?

Comment: This is just a minimal code example, in real usage this construct is a multi level inherited state machine for game logic of a character.

Comment: A delegate to a virtual method will run the inherited version... I'm not sure the problem is what you think it is... can you provide a *runnable* example?

Comment: 1) doesn't seem like a lot of useless code here.. 2) just rename your methods to avoid confusion.. 3) just make the intermediary method of the base class private.. I see nothing wrong with this, apart from using an apparently useless delegate.

Comment: Runnable example provided, but thanks to Bubblewrap, this question is answered. Oh, and when you have 3 levels of inheritance with 20+ states the useless code starts to add up quite a bit.

Comment: are you sure youve posted the code correctly, the inherited method should be called correctly

Comment: About the first example running, I have no idea why it works. Stripped it down from semi-working code, perhaps another error somewhere else is also present, if not an WTF tag should be appropriate, or a not-enough-coffee perhaps? Will investigate and if i find something i'll add it here. Again, help you for your help.

Comment: I think i got what happened, as stupid as it sounds it looks like my debugging was flawed. Well, sorry for the mess, hope you enjoyed my WTF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could replace `next=DoMethod;` with `next= ()=>Method();` which is essentially the same, but doesn't require you to define an extra method on your class.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know this language construct.

Comment: You're welcome, but before you use this, you might want to look at some of the comments suggesting that your initial approach should work.

Comment: Yes, I see those, just um, WTF, i tried that with not the effect. Perhaps i got an error somewhere else too.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>In your first example, you are assigning the **result** of `Method();` to the delegate, so naturally that means that the `Method` method (ahem) will be executed at that point to assign a value. Ignoring the fact that `Method` is `void` (which won't compile).</strike>

In the second example, you are assigning a reference to the method (which doesn't have to be an instance method) to the delegate, which allows you to execute the `del` at a later stage.

The following works for me:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var baseClass = new BaseObject();
        baseClass.Execute();

        var derivedClass = new DerivedObject();
        derivedClass.Execute();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class BaseObject
{
    public delegate void SomethingDelegate();
    public SomethingDelegate Delegate;

    public BaseObject()
    {
        Delegate += Something;
    }

    public virtual void Something()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base Class");
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        Delegate();
    }
}

class DerivedObject : BaseObject
{
    public override void Something()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived Class");
    }
}
```

In the above example, the fact that the delegate pointer is expressed as a pointer to the `Something` method (of `BaseObject`), because the method is virtual, the call is still correctly dispatched to the overriden `Something` method (of `DerivedObject`).

Are you not seeing the same behaviour?

Comment: But the return type of `Method` is `void`, so that can't be assigned to a delegate. The first example simply doesn't compile.

Comment: @Guffa - His original code (before he edited) was `del = Method();` which will not compile. He has updated his code since then.

Answer (score 3):

No, `Execute` will run the inherited method. After making some correction to the code I could test it:

```
public class BaseObject {
  public delegate void del();

  public BaseObject() {
    next = Method;
  }

  public del next;
  public void Execute() {
    next();
  }

  public virtual void Method() {
    Console.WriteLine("base");
  }
}

public class InheritedObject : BaseObject {

  override public void Method() {
    Console.WriteLine("inherited");
  }

}
```

Called:

```
(new InheritedObject()).Execute();
```

Output:

```
inherited
```